# MySQL Divide Derived Columns

Tags: mysql, database, sum, division

How can I divide to generated columns in a MySQL select? I have two database, one with questions and one with attempts. I want to pull up the attempt data for a specific question with the number of attempts, incorrect_attempts, and correct_attempts. Then I want to divide the correct attempts by the number of attempts (preferably if the attempts is greater than 0).

Here is an example query, but it does not work:

```
SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN qa.id > 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) attempts, 
    SUM(CASE WHEN qa.correct = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) correct_attempts, 
    SUM(CASE WHEN qa.correct = 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) incorrect_attempts,
    (100 * correct_attempts / attempts) percentage
FROM test_questions tq
LEFT JOIN question_attempts qa ON qa.question_id = tq.id
GROUP BY id
```

Also, if I can get this to work, what function do I use to return the percentage to two decimal points?

Here's some example data:

```
{
    "table": "question_attempts",
    "rows":
    [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "question_id": 1,
            "user_id": 8,
            "correct": 1,
            "created_at": "2017-01-13 12:17:42"
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "question_id": 1,
            "user_id": 8,
            "correct": 0,
            "created_at": "2017-01-13 12:17:32"
        }
    ],
    "table": "test_questions",
    "rows":
    [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "question": "..."
        }
    ]
}
```

The result I want should look like the following:

```
{
    "rows":
    [
        {           
            "attempts": 2,
            "correct_attempts": 1,
            "incorrect_attempts": 1,
            "percentage": 50.00,            
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: so if you add a select on top of this query and then find the percentage it should work  and for round you can use build in functions of sql

Comment: if you provide me sample data I can try

Comment: You can't reference aliases "declared" in the SELECT clause later in the SELECT clause (or anywhere else but the HAVING clause or an outer enclosing query, MSSQL won't even let you reference them in HAVING clauses). You can either do as @YashveerSingh suggested, or duplicate your sum expressions and divide one by the other (i.e. `SUM(x)/SUM(y)` is fine)